# how to distinguish double and single tabs in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

I have different csvs where delimeter is tab. I changed the tab with semicolon and it worked. but now I came to a situation where some csv has double tab

```
         Dan Ura(UTC)   A   B   C
20160101 0000   2.7     83.0
20160101 0100   3.8     83.0
20160101 0200   9       82.0
20160101 0300   -6      84.0
```

I am trying to read it as

```
 df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\TEST.csv', sep='\t+', engine='python',skiprows=1)
```

it gives output as

```
   Date Time       A    B  C
10/1/2020 0000  250  35 Nan
11/1/2020 0005  300 25  Nan
11/1/2020 0010  120  360  Nan
```

but here double tabs means that values are of C column and B column has null values. with one tab values belong to column B and with 2 tabs values goes to column c. How can I specify it while reading csv? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you update your post with first lines of your raw file, please?

Comment: can you try in read_csv with `sep='\t'`, without the + sign?

Comment: Does the data really have tabs? In the two data examples there aren't any.

Comment: @Corralien now it's exactly same data as csv has

Comment: @Ben.T I did tried but same result

Comment: First you can replace the double tabs with semocolon and then the single tabs. So you will gat clear data to read

Comment: If I replace tabs with semicolon then it will not give me null values for column B

Comment: Try: `df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\TEST.csv', sep='\t', engine='python', skiprows=1, skipinitialspace=True)`

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Corralien yes it solved the problem. thank you for the help.